# CSS-only reverse (un)ordered list

Tags: css, flexbox, html-lists

Plugin I'm using outputs links/descriptions as list items. If possible, I'd like to reverse the order (so first li appears last on the page) but also have them appear across two columns in masonry-esque (vs grid) fashion?

Existing code I have is:

```
.post-entry #linkcat-0 ul {
-moz-column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-count: 2;
column-count: 2;
-moz-column-gap: 1em;
-webkit-column-gap: 1em;
column-gap: 1em; }

.post-entry #linkcat-0 ul li {
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
border: 0;
padding: 10px 0;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #999; }

.post-entry #linkcat-0 ul li:last-child {
border-bottom: 0; }
```

Flex was introduced after I stopped dabbling, so I can't seem to get the two to work together. If anyone might be able to offer any insight, that would be very much appreciated.

In action: https://jsfiddle.net/z97xgp4k/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that is exactly how you wanted it to look like but I believe that is relatively close.

That is the code I ended up with:

```
.post-entry #linkcat-0 ul {
    columns: 2;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
} 
.post-entry #linkcat-0 ul li {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #999;
}
```

You can see how it looks [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8yxeg24h/7/).

Hope it helps.